# Sorting Before Sending the Output to Terminal

Tags: sort

I have below script that I get details of some IPs in a blacklist.

**check.sh**

```
blacklist_ips='
    5.56.148.140
    94.73.159.66
    113.171.224.169
    107.150.42.226
    195.159.233.44
    89.19.7.58
'

for ipx in $blacklist_ips
do
    country=`whois $ipx | grep -i country | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
    hostx=`host $ipx |awk '{print $NF}'|sed "s/\.$//"`
    printf '%s %s %s' $country $ipx $hostx          
    printf '\n'
done
```

It works but I want to sort the output by country section.

Now I can simply go:

```
bash check.sh | sort -nr
```

and it works OK.

But I want to do the sorting before sending the result to terminal. In other words sorting should be done inside `check.sh` and then should be sent to terminal.

How can I achieve this in bash script?

Comment: change the print statements to: `printf '%s %s %s\n' $country $ipx $hostx > file.txt` then add `sort -nr file.txt` after the for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not want to clutter the folder with another file. Is it possible to do it without file i/o?

Comment: How many IP addresses are you looking at? There's only so much a bash script variable can hold. Would simply removing the file at the end of the script work?

Comment: Well the script can be used by mutliple cron jobs or scripts. So I am a bit afraid of race condition. Do not want to read output of a previous script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change the final `done` to `done | sort -nr`

This will sort the output of the `for` loop via a pipe and not need temporary files.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your help. How can I add conditional for `done | sort -nr` please? For some conditionals, I would like to run as `done | sort -nrk2`? I tried to convert last line of for to a if conditional but it gave syntax error.

Comment: Lots of ways.  One simple way is to just set a variable `order=nr` or `order=nrk2` before the `for` loop based on the condition, then you can do `sort -$order`